# How do you pass all the contents of a ListBoxFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am currently binding an IEnumerable collection to a ListBoxFor, which works as expected, sending the currently selected values on POST. However, I need to send all the values instead (essentially any value in a given ListBoxFor I consider to be required, whether selected or not). How would I go about doing this?

(I can probably rig something up in jQuery where, on-submit, it manually selects all the elements in a box, but was wondering if there was a better way.)

Comment: Are you talking about the labels which are present in the listbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to continue using normal browser form serialization on submit, write a javascript function to fire right before the submission (hook into an onclick event or something) which iterates through the list box control and concatenates the desired values (perhaps comma-delimited) and places it in a hidden field. The value of that hidden field will be submitted normally and you can parse the individual values from it on the server side. It's still some manual work, but you avoid messing with GUI state (i.e. selecting all desired list box items) which I agree is something you don't want to do.

Comment: Alright, that's probably the route I'll go. Found a duplicate question here too that suggests the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/955581/how-should-i-obtain-complete-list-contents-after-a-post

Comment: Cool, I've used it successfully for years: in my case, I've had "dual list box" controls where options could be moved between the two list boxes, where the one on the right-hand side would be the "selected" items, and so all items in that list box needed to be submitted. The only thing you need to make sure of is that you actually wire-up the select box items -> hidden field function (some times I've forgotten and wondered why my updates weren't being saved).

Comment: The suggestion the other answer makes is similar but a little different than mine. I think it's a bit more complicated since there is a lot more state with indirect connections involved and thus things that could go wrong (adding and removing individual hidden fields representing each list item dynamically). In my approach, there is only one point of failure.